# MvvmCross RaisePropertyChanged

Tags: c#, mvvmcross, win-universal-app, inotifypropertychanged

In order to get MvvmCross PropertyChanged event in the Universal App I had to set ShouldAlwaysRaiseInpcOnUserInterfaceThread(false). Could you please explain why it so? I found this method accidentally after 3 hours of investigating why binding is not working. Once this method is called everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

`RaisePropertyChanged` by default marshals `PropertyChanged` events to the UI thread. So if there's no Dispatcher set (e.g in unit tests), your event will not be raised at all. So you set

```
ShouldAlwaysRaiseInpcOnUserInterfaceThread(false);
```

For more details please see [this](http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20140324-HandlingPropertyChangedEventInMvvmCrossViewModelUnitTests.html)

Comment: But I have not written tests, I just run an application with F5 (Local Machine) and binding is not working. Is this OK? Will I need to call ShouldAlwaysRaiseInpcOnUserInterfaceThread after application is released?